# Vivado Video IPs not working as expected

Tags: video, vga, vivado, zynq, microblaze

I've been trying to understand how to utilize AXI-Stream IPs for Video processing and display via VGA for a few days now, but can't seem to get any circuit to work. Here is a test circuit I created:

[image]

I have a Video Test Pattern Generator connected to an Axi4-stream to Video Out IP driven by a Video Timing Controller IP. Here is a 100 ms simulation for the circuit:

[image]

Vsync does not get generated so clearly there is something wrong with this circuit.

All examples I have found online include a MicroBlaze or Zynq processor with their design connected to the VTPG, could this be a reason my circuit is not working? Is it possible to do what I am trying to without a processor? What exactly is the role of a processor in these circuits?

My development board is a Nexys 4 DDR. I've gotten VGA to display in the past using IPs I created myself, but they weren't AXI compliant.

Any guidance would be appreciated! Here is a tcl script for my block design:

```
################################################################
# This is a generated script based on design: design_1
#
# Though there are limitations about the generated script,
# the main purpose of this utility is to make learning
# IP Integrator Tcl commands easier.
################################################################

namespace eval _tcl {
proc get_script_folder {} {
   set script_path [file normalize [info script]]
   set script_folder [file dirname $script_path]
   return $script_folder
}
}
variable script_folder
set script_folder [_tcl::get_script_folder]

################################################################
# Check if script is running in correct Vivado version.
################################################################
set scripts_vivado_version 2018.1
set current_vivado_version [version -short]

if { [string first $scripts_vivado_version $current_vivado_version] == -1 } {
   puts ""
   catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-109" "ERROR" "This script was generated using Vivado <$scripts_vivado_version> and is being run in <$current_vivado_version> of Vivado. Please run the script in Vivado <$scripts_vivado_version> then open the design in Vivado <$current_vivado_version>. Upgrade the design by running \"Tools => Report => Report IP Status...\", then run write_bd_tcl to create an updated script."}

   return 1
}

################################################################
# START
################################################################

# To test this script, run the following commands from Vivado Tcl console:
# source design_1_script.tcl

# If there is no project opened, this script will create a
# project, but make sure you do not have an existing project
# <./myproj/project_1.xpr> in the current working folder.

set list_projs [get_projects -quiet]
if { $list_projs eq "" } {
   create_project project_1 myproj -part xc7a100tcsg324-1
}


# CHANGE DESIGN NAME HERE
variable design_name
set design_name design_1

# If you do not already have an existing IP Integrator design open,
# you can create a design using the following command:
#    create_bd_design $design_name

# Creating design if needed
set errMsg ""
set nRet 0

set cur_design [current_bd_design -quiet]
set list_cells [get_bd_cells -quiet]

if { ${design_name} eq "" } {
   # USE CASES:
   #    1) Design_name not set

   set errMsg "Please set the variable <design_name> to a non-empty value."
   set nRet 1

} elseif { ${cur_design} ne "" && ${list_cells} eq "" } {
   # USE CASES:
   #    2): Current design opened AND is empty AND names same.
   #    3): Current design opened AND is empty AND names diff; design_name NOT in project.
   #    4): Current design opened AND is empty AND names diff; design_name exists in project.

   if { $cur_design ne $design_name } {
      common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-001" "INFO" "Changing value of <design_name> from <$design_name> to <$cur_design> since current design is empty."
      set design_name [get_property NAME $cur_design]
   }
   common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-002" "INFO" "Constructing design in IPI design <$cur_design>..."

} elseif { ${cur_design} ne "" && $list_cells ne "" && $cur_design eq $design_name } {
   # USE CASES:
   #    5) Current design opened AND has components AND same names.

   set errMsg "Design <$design_name> already exists in your project, please set the variable <design_name> to another value."
   set nRet 1
} elseif { [get_files -quiet ${design_name}.bd] ne "" } {
   # USE CASES: 
   #    6) Current opened design, has components, but diff names, design_name exists in project.
   #    7) No opened design, design_name exists in project.

   set errMsg "Design <$design_name> already exists in your project, please set the variable <design_name> to another value."
   set nRet 2

} else {
   # USE CASES:
   #    8) No opened design, design_name not in project.
   #    9) Current opened design, has components, but diff names, design_name not in project.

   common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-003" "INFO" "Currently there is no design <$design_name> in project, so creating one..."

   create_bd_design $design_name

   common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-004" "INFO" "Making design <$design_name> as current_bd_design."
   current_bd_design $design_name

}

common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-005" "INFO" "Currently the variable <design_name> is equal to \"$design_name\"."

if { $nRet != 0 } {
   catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-114" "ERROR" $errMsg}
   return $nRet
}

set bCheckIPsPassed 1
##################################################################
# CHECK IPs
##################################################################
set bCheckIPs 1
if { $bCheckIPs == 1 } {
   set list_check_ips "\ 
xilinx.com:ip:xlslice:1.0\
xilinx.com:ip:v_axi4s_vid_out:4.0\
xilinx.com:ip:v_tc:6.1\
xilinx.com:ip:v_tpg:7.0\
xilinx.com:ip:xlconstant:1.1\
"

   set list_ips_missing ""
   common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-006" "INFO" "Checking if the following IPs exist in the project's IP catalog: $list_check_ips ."

   foreach ip_vlnv $list_check_ips {
      set ip_obj [get_ipdefs -all $ip_vlnv]
      if { $ip_obj eq "" } {
         lappend list_ips_missing $ip_vlnv
      }
   }

   if { $list_ips_missing ne "" } {
      catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-115" "ERROR" "The following IPs are not found in the IP Catalog:\n  $list_ips_missing\n\nResolution: Please add the repository containing the IP(s) to the project." }
      set bCheckIPsPassed 0
   }

}

if { $bCheckIPsPassed != 1 } {
  common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-1003" "WARNING" "Will not continue with creation of design due to the error(s) above."
  return 3
}

##################################################################
# DESIGN PROCs
##################################################################



# Procedure to create entire design; Provide argument to make
# procedure reusable. If parentCell is "", will use root.
proc create_root_design { parentCell } {

  variable script_folder
  variable design_name

  if { $parentCell eq "" } {
     set parentCell [get_bd_cells /]
  }

  # Get object for parentCell
  set parentObj [get_bd_cells $parentCell]
  if { $parentObj == "" } {
     catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-100" "ERROR" "Unable to find parent cell <$parentCell>!"}
     return
  }

  # Make sure parentObj is hier blk
  set parentType [get_property TYPE $parentObj]
  if { $parentType ne "hier" } {
     catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-101" "ERROR" "Parent <$parentObj> has TYPE = <$parentType>. Expected to be <hier>."}
     return
  }

  # Save current instance; Restore later
  set oldCurInst [current_bd_instance .]

  # Set parent object as current
  current_bd_instance $parentObj


  # Create interface ports

  # Create ports
  set ap_clk_0 [ create_bd_port -dir I -type clk ap_clk_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.FREQ_HZ {150000000} \
 ] $ap_clk_0
  set resetn_0 [ create_bd_port -dir I -type rst resetn_0 ]
  set vga_blue [ create_bd_port -dir O -from 3 -to 0 vga_blue ]
  set vga_green [ create_bd_port -dir O -from 3 -to 0 vga_green ]
  set vga_hsync [ create_bd_port -dir O vga_hsync ]
  set vga_red [ create_bd_port -dir O -from 3 -to 0 vga_red ]
  set vga_vsync [ create_bd_port -dir O vga_vsync ]

  # Create instance: slice_blue, and set properties
  set slice_blue [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:xlslice:1.0 slice_blue ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.DIN_FROM {7} \
   CONFIG.DIN_TO {4} \
   CONFIG.DIN_WIDTH {24} \
   CONFIG.DOUT_WIDTH {4} \
 ] $slice_blue

  # Create instance: slice_green, and set properties
  set slice_green [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:xlslice:1.0 slice_green ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.DIN_FROM {15} \
   CONFIG.DIN_TO {12} \
   CONFIG.DIN_WIDTH {24} \
   CONFIG.DOUT_WIDTH {4} \
 ] $slice_green

  # Create instance: slice_red, and set properties
  set slice_red [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:xlslice:1.0 slice_red ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.DIN_FROM {23} \
   CONFIG.DIN_TO {20} \
   CONFIG.DIN_WIDTH {24} \
   CONFIG.DOUT_WIDTH {4} \
 ] $slice_red

  # Create instance: v_axi4s_vid_out_0, and set properties
  set v_axi4s_vid_out_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:v_axi4s_vid_out:4.0 v_axi4s_vid_out_0 ]

  # Create instance: v_tc_0, and set properties
  set v_tc_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:v_tc:6.1 v_tc_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.GEN_F0_VBLANK_HEND {640} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F0_VBLANK_HSTART {640} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F0_VFRAME_SIZE {525} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F0_VSYNC_HEND {640} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F0_VSYNC_HSTART {640} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F0_VSYNC_VEND {491} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F0_VSYNC_VSTART {489} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F1_VBLANK_HEND {640} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F1_VBLANK_HSTART {640} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F1_VFRAME_SIZE {525} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F1_VSYNC_HEND {640} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F1_VSYNC_HSTART {640} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F1_VSYNC_VEND {491} \
   CONFIG.GEN_F1_VSYNC_VSTART {489} \
   CONFIG.GEN_HACTIVE_SIZE {640} \
   CONFIG.GEN_HFRAME_SIZE {800} \
   CONFIG.GEN_HSYNC_END {752} \
   CONFIG.GEN_HSYNC_START {656} \
   CONFIG.GEN_VACTIVE_SIZE {480} \
   CONFIG.HAS_AXI4_LITE {false} \
   CONFIG.VIDEO_MODE {640x480p} \
   CONFIG.enable_detection {false} \
 ] $v_tc_0

  # Create instance: v_tpg_0, and set properties
  set v_tpg_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:v_tpg:7.0 v_tpg_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.MAX_COLS {640} \
   CONFIG.MAX_ROWS {480} \
 ] $v_tpg_0

  # Create instance: xlconstant_0, and set properties
  set xlconstant_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:xlconstant:1.1 xlconstant_0 ]

  # Create interface connections
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net v_tc_0_vtiming_out [get_bd_intf_pins v_axi4s_vid_out_0/vtiming_in] [get_bd_intf_pins v_tc_0/vtiming_out]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net v_tpg_0_m_axis_video [get_bd_intf_pins v_axi4s_vid_out_0/video_in] [get_bd_intf_pins v_tpg_0/m_axis_video]

  # Create port connections
  connect_bd_net -net ap_clk_0_1 [get_bd_ports ap_clk_0] [get_bd_pins v_axi4s_vid_out_0/aclk] [get_bd_pins v_tc_0/clk] [get_bd_pins v_tpg_0/ap_clk]
  connect_bd_net -net resetn_0_1 [get_bd_ports resetn_0] [get_bd_pins v_tpg_0/ap_rst_n]
  connect_bd_net -net slice_blue_Dout [get_bd_ports vga_blue] [get_bd_pins slice_blue/Dout]
  connect_bd_net -net slice_green_Dout [get_bd_ports vga_green] [get_bd_pins slice_green/Dout]
  connect_bd_net -net slice_red_Dout [get_bd_ports vga_red] [get_bd_pins slice_red/Dout]
  connect_bd_net -net v_axi4s_vid_out_0_vid_data [get_bd_pins slice_blue/Din] [get_bd_pins slice_green/Din] [get_bd_pins slice_red/Din] [get_bd_pins v_axi4s_vid_out_0/vid_data]
  connect_bd_net -net v_axi4s_vid_out_0_vid_hsync [get_bd_ports vga_hsync] [get_bd_pins v_axi4s_vid_out_0/vid_hsync]
  connect_bd_net -net v_axi4s_vid_out_0_vid_vsync [get_bd_ports vga_vsync] [get_bd_pins v_axi4s_vid_out_0/vid_vsync]
  connect_bd_net -net v_axi4s_vid_out_0_vtg_ce [get_bd_pins v_axi4s_vid_out_0/vtg_ce] [get_bd_pins v_tc_0/gen_clken]
  connect_bd_net -net xlconstant_0_dout [get_bd_pins v_axi4s_vid_out_0/aclken] [get_bd_pins v_axi4s_vid_out_0/vid_io_out_ce] [get_bd_pins v_tc_0/clken] [get_bd_pins xlconstant_0/dout]

  # Create address segments


  # Restore current instance
  current_bd_instance $oldCurInst

  save_bd_design
}
# End of create_root_design()


##################################################################
# MAIN FLOW
##################################################################

create_root_design ""
```

Comment: You don't need a soft processor to use AXI or AXI stream.  I do lots of work with AXI stream, and none of it currently involves soft cores.

Comment: Cool good to know. Guess that means I have to keep troubleshooting my circuit

Comment: You don't need a processor for AXI streams. They are designed to transport high volume data without processor. e.g. I have a Video generator with three AXIS outputs to test BTC blocks. (Which also have AXI-stream outputs.)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your connection diagram.
I don't know what all the blocks are supposed to do. You need to read the datasheets for them. Xilinx have a description for each IP core, but what I remember they can be difficult to find.

**v_tpg_0**
Has an AXI control bus:s_axi_CTRL. It can very well be that you need to setup the block with an external CPU to get correct video data out.

**v_tc_0**
Has a `resetn` input which is not driven.

**v_axi4s_vid_out_0**
 - Also has a `aresetn` input which is not driven.
 - Also seems to have a axi slave interface which is not connected. The same as for the v_tpg_0 you probably need to connect a CPU and set register inside the IP block.
 - `fid` is not connected. I don't know what it does but it is not recommended to keep inputs unconnected.

So it looks like you need a CPU which drives the s_axis interfaces. I worked with Zynq systems which have an ARM core and a AXI master bus which you need to connect to your slave buses. You will need an AXI splitter to get from one master bus to two slave buses. Anther IP block from Xilinx.

Last remarks:
I find it very strange that you have a pattern generator with separate timing controller which work in parallel and have no synchronization between them. I don't think that can work.
Have a look what the m_axis_video output has as signals. Also check if it matches up with the signals in video_in. I would expect a video pattern generator to have the full signal set at the output: data, hsync, vsync. Mine have!

Tip: It helps if you give constant blocks the name of the output. e.g. if you generate a constant one call it as such: "gen_one" or "make_one"